# how to mount ipv6 address to linux

Tags: networking, ip, fedora, ipv6, ipv4

I am trying to mount a folder from ubuntu system having ip ipv6 as well as ipv4 address

```
root@:/home# ifconfig
br0       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 16:37:81:2e:ce:e9  
          inet addr:10.0.3.24  Bcast:10.0.7.255  Mask:255.255.248.0
          inet6 addr: 2001:db8::60fe:5bff:febc:912/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: 2001:db8::e8a6:7d68:16b8:3d86/64 Scope:Global
```

I can able to ping ipv6 address from different linux system  :

```
[root@Abhitesh home]# ping6 2001:db8::60fe:5bff:febc:912
PING 2001:db8::60fe:5bff:febc:912(2001:db8::60fe:5bff:febc:912) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 2001:db8::60fe:5bff:febc:912: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.968 ms
64 bytes from 2001:db8::60fe:5bff:febc:912: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=1.07 ms
```

I am getting error, when i am trying to mount with `ipv6`

```
[root@Abhitesh home]# mount -t nfs 2001:db8::60fe:5bff:febc:912:/home/abhitesh /home/mount/
mount.nfs: mount system call failed
[root@Abhitesh home]#
```

with `ipv4` mount command is working.

Is that my command is wrong or i need to configure something, to mount with `ipv6`.

In my system `ipv6` is enabled.

```
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/disable_ipv6
0
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Command is wrong NFS mount command should be

`mount -t nfs [2001:db8::60fe:5bff:febc:912]:/home/abhitesh /home/mount/`

`IPv6` address should be in `[]`.

and for `CIFS` mount command should be

`mount -t cifs -o username=xxxx,password=yyyyy //2001:db8::60fe:5bff:febc:914/public /home/mount`

Answer (score 1):

For those who might ever need it, posting below the entries that worked for me. Using Arch linux and link-local IPv6 addresses.

/etc/exports entry on the server

```
/dir1    fe80::blah:blah:blah:blah(rw,sync,nohide)
```

/etc/fstab entry on client

```
[fe80::boom:boom:boom:boom%wlan0]:/dir1    /home/a/b/c    nfs    noatime,noauto,users    0 0
```

Command when mounting manually

```
sudo mount [fe80::boom:boom:boom:boom%wlan0]:/dir1 /home/a/b/c
```